# sync sharepoint list with Active directory

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

Just wondering if anyone can help me with a problem i am having.
in work we have office 365 synced with Active directory and i want to know if i could do the following.
we have a employee details list on sharepoint which holds all an employees contact number including the following; work numner, home number and mobile. we use this list to update an employees details, so for example if an employee gets a new number we would update the employee details list on sharepoint. can i sync this list with AD directory so that when i update an employees details on the sharepoint list the changes are also made to active directory ? any guidance on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This issue cannot be solved using SharePoint out-of-box features, so I advise you try the third-part tool, such as [AD Information Sync](http://www.boostsolutions.com/active-directory-sync.html). 
This tool can sync the user, contact or computer information from AD to SharePoint list, also can update the changes between AD and list.